# Arquillian Testing Issue

Tags: java, maven, testing, jboss-arquillian

I have a java application that uses the Arquillian library for testing. I am attempting to now add the Arquillian reporter extension. As shown in the documentation at https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-recorder/wiki/Reporter, I have added the dependency to my pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.arquillian.extension</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-recorder-reporter-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

However, now when I build my project, which worked before adding this new dependency, I get the error shown below.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:160)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:111)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:97)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.build(TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.java:52)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.testng.Arquillian.arquillianBeforeSuite(Arquillian.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:543)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:212)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:277)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:87)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1062)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:974)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:69)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeMulti(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:181)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:99)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:113)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
    ....
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.event.suite.BeforeTestLifecycleEvent
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2570)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1855)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.Reflections.getObserverMethods(Reflections.java:52)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ExtensionImpl.of(ExtensionImpl.java:51)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.createExtensions(ManagerImpl.java:440)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fireProcessing(ManagerImpl.java:375)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.<init>(ManagerImpl.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:156)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:111)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:97)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.ManagerBuilder.create(ManagerBuilder.java:77)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.<init>(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:156)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:111)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:97)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.build(TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.java:52)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.testng.Arquillian.arquillianBeforeSuite(Arquillian.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:543)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:212)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Arquillian version needs to be updated to support the recorder.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by a conflict between different versions of Arquillian. This error is resolved by updating from 1.1.5.Final to:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.8.Final</version>
    <scope>import</scope>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```